# Is anyone else experiencing very high CPU usage on the site?

Tags: support

For the time I have been visitng the site, I have opened it up first thing in the morning in my browser (Vimprobable) and then, periodically throughout the day, reloaded the page to see new questions and answers.

Some time over the last 24 or—so hours, I have noticed that if I reload the site once, it sends my CPU to 100% where it remains until I close the page.

The only change that I have noticed is the new javascript "thing"<sup>1</sup> that announces new activity on the top of the page.

Is this a bug? Nothing else in my setup has changed.

**System details**
Arch Linux. Vimprobable2 0.9.12.0 libwebkit 1.6.3 libsoup 2.36.1

**Edit:** This behaviour doesn't happen on Stackoverflow...

<strike>**Edit 2:** I have (I think) narrowed it down to the ads that appears in the sidebar (Love Your Community etc); on some page reloads, the ad is blocked and that is when the CPU spikes.</strike>

I have been using privoxy, but this domain is listed under both 'fragile' and 'allow ads' - so the ads should be displayed at all times AFAIK.
[Hypothesis discounted...]

<sup>1. Technical term...</sup>

Comment: What are your system specs - browser version - os, and any other details you might have.

Comment: I have updated my post with some more detail: let me know if you need more. Also, disabling javascript has no effect - CPU still hits 100%

Comment: Without javascript enabled there's really no way the notifications will function.  Could you try another browser?

Comment: Seems to work fine in Firefox; no CPU spikes...

Comment: I cannot tell you why this is happening - I'll see if I can build up a VM to test the config you have running.  Honestly I have never used Vimprobable2.

Comment: Thanks Geoff: I'm aware it is an extreme corner case - I was more interested to see if anyone else was experiencing it. As it is confined to my setup, I'd not worry too much about it.

Comment: Confirmed the same behaviour on my laptop (running the same software), so it is not hardware-related. All my configs are [in this repo](http://beta.intuxication.org/jasonwryan/archer/browse/tip/)

Answer (score 3):

We don't officially support this browser however I will do my best to see if I can reproduce this issue.

Comment: An update: for the last day it has worked fine. Not sure how much overlap there is with the javascript being disabled (as it appears to be).

Comment: Well, it was nice while it lasted... CPU spikes returned today with the activity notification script.